# How do I dismiss a dialog when working with on a fragment?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog reference that I want to dismiss. I have an issue is that I can't just dismiss the reference it to from my dialog, here is the code from my Fragment so you can understand why -

```
@OnClick(R.id.verification_button_got_it)
    void onBtnGotItClicked(View view) {
        if (!checkBoxAge.isChecked()) {
            checkBoxAge.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(checkBoxAge.getContext(), R.color.accent_red));
            return;
        }
        showProgressDialog();
        if (getContext() instanceof VerificationPageListener) {
            ((VerificationPageListener) getContext()).onPageAgreed();
        }
    }

private void showProgressDialog(){
        if (mBuilder == null) {
            mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(App.getAppContext());
        }
        mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        mBuilder.setView(R.layout.custom_proggress_dialog);
        mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }
```

At the point that you see "onPageAgreed()" is the point where the data is being sent to the server to verify the device IMEI for verification purpose, so if I dismiss the dialog at that point than the dialog will not show at all because it will be immediate.

As I said, this is a Fragment that sits on top of activity, so the activity handles the entire checking through the DB thing. Here is the code of the activity handling the database checking and moving the results to the presenter -

```
@Override
  public void onPageAgreed() {
    // current page is accepted, move to next
    int cur = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (cur == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
      // ask for permission
      requestPhoneState();
    } else {
      // move to next
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(cur + 1, true);
    }
  }

  private void requestPhoneState() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, RC_PERMISSION_READ_STATE);
    } else {
      // retrieve IMEI
      accessDeviceIdAndVerifyDB(this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRequestPermissionsResultPostResume(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResultPostResume(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == RC_PERMISSION_READ_STATE
        && permissions.length > 0 && StringUtils.equals(permissions[0], Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // granted, read IMEI
      accessDeviceIdAndVerifyDB(this);
    } else {
      // failed
      onErrorDeviceIdNotGrantedPermission();
    }
  }

  private void accessDeviceIdAndVerifyDB(Activity activity) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      if (telephonyManager != null) {
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(deviceId)) {
          checkDeviceIdWithDB(deviceId);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void checkDeviceIdWithDB(String deviceId) {
    presenter.onDeviceIdReceived(deviceId);
  }
```

It seems like I am stuck in a loop where I have to move a reference of my dialog all over a few classes just in order to cancel it, which seems really broken. How can I cancel my dialog more easily?

edit -

I have added this code before the point where the activity is being finished -

```
@Override
  public void sendDeviceIdResult(String deviceId, boolean isAlreadyExist) {

    int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Fragment item = adapter.getItem(currentItem);
    if (item instanceof PhoneStateAndAgeVerificationFragment) {
      Dialog dialog = ((PhoneStateAndAgeVerificationFragment) item).getProgressDialog();
      if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_IS_SUCCESS, !isAlreadyExist);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();


  }
```

but at this point my dialog is always null and I can't figure out if at this point it will be always null and the check is redundant or I am doing something total wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close your `dialog` that is in your `frament` from your `activity` using interfaces.

In activity create an interface like following.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompactActivity{

  public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void closeDialog();
  }

  onSomeEventListener someEventListener;
  //.............

@Override
  public void onPageAgreed() {
    // current page is accepted, move to next
    int cur = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (cur == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
      // ask for permission
      requestPhoneState();
    } else {
      // move to next
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(cur + 1, true);
    }

   //you can add below line in your activity from where you can close your dialog. 
   someEventListener.closeDialog();
  }
```

In your `fragment` you have to implement that interface like below

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements onSomeEventListener{

  @Override
  public void closeDialog() {
      // here you can close your dialog
      if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
      }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your `sendDeviceIdResult()` you can simplify the code using the above interface like below.

```
@Override
  public void sendDeviceIdResult(String deviceId, boolean isAlreadyExist) {

    int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Fragment item = adapter.getItem(currentItem);
    if (item instanceof PhoneStateAndAgeVerificationFragment) {
       someEventListener = item; // initialize your interface here instead of onCreate()
       someEventListener.closeDialog(); 
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_IS_SUCCESS, !isAlreadyExist);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();


  }
```

Comment: This solution will not work as if you see my code, requestPhoneState navigates through other function that have network request that will take much more time than the function ending, resulting in the dialog immediately popping off because it won't have time to be shown.

Comment: The thing is that, as you can see in my code, I am not instantiating the fragment variable inside my activity but I am creating a new adapter that does that forme, therefore I am not holding a PhoneStateAndAgeVerificationFragment variable to instantiate it as an interface. I am adding a solution that might help to the original post, please check it and see if I am doing well.

Comment: I have mistakenly edited your post, ignore it. Please check the edit on my post.